# Updating the state of the Home Page component from a IonModal getting a useEffect error

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, redux, use-effect

I have an IonModal that I'm using to add data to my database through an API call. I will then add the response data to a list in my Redux store which is being displayed on the Home Page.

This function is being called on a button press within my modal to call the API, get the response, add it to the store, and close the modal:

```
const addData = async () => {
  const transaction = await createTransaction(data);
  dispatch(addTransaction(transaction));
  setShowModal(false);
};
```

createTransaction is calling the API and returning the response data.

When it is called and the modal is closed I am getting this error

**Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.**

In my Home page all I have is a simple useEffect that sets the state within the component to the state within the redux store and should update displayed content within the component but isn't:

```
const transactions = useSelector(state => state.transactions);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  setData(transactions);
}, [transactions]);
```

The data does get successfully added to the Redux Store but it just  doesn't get updated visually on the home page.

Any help or advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding data to the useEffect array like so: `useEffect(() => {}, [transactions, data])`. Essentially what the useEffect hook does is re-render each time it senses a change in a state variable. So your data state variable is getting updated; however, it's not being updated visually because it's not being told to rerender on the data change.